# how to execute truncate table with snowflake python connector?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I intend to write a python script that will upload csv files to a table in snowflake. I'll be using the python connector.

But, before uploading the data, I want to remove all previous records from the table.

I'm having trouble finding a way to truncate the table every time I run the script.

Comment: What have you tried? How are you inserting into the table right now? can you provide a code sample? I think you need some more information in your question before anyone can help you.

Comment: Hi, so the suggestion made by Marcel works. This is my code snippet:

    conn = snowflake.connector.connect(
        user=os.environ.get("USER_NAME"),
        password=os.environ.get("PASSWORD"),
        account=os.environ.get("ACCOUNT"),
        warehouse=os.environ.get("WAREHOUSE"),
        database=os.environ.get("DATABASE"),
        schema=os.environ.get("SCHEMA"),
        role=os.environ.get("ROLE"))
    conn.cursor().execute("truncate [table_name]")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are loading the data by running a COPY INTO -command. Actually there is no parameter like "OVERWRITE=TRUE" - this parameter only exists for unloading data to a stage (i.e. COPY INTO ) but not loading from your stage into Snowflake.

Consequence: You have to run a truncate-statement before your COPY INTO-statement.

```
TRUNCATE TABLE IF EXISTS myTable;

COPY INTO ...
```